# there was a building a few miles into the town

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Is this idiomatic to say,

> There was a building a few miles into the town.

Somehow, this preposition "into" makes me uneasy. I think it sounds a little strange, but I'm no native. Is it grammatical and idiomatic to write/say this sentence?

Comment: I think *a few miles **away from** town* would work.

Comment: Do you mean a few miles *inside* the town (from outside the town going a few miles past the city limits)?

Comment: @user3169 Yes. I think the better way of saying it (according to photon) is "_There was a building a few miles into the city_." Does this sound idiomatic to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not incorrect, but it's not a common expression.

It would mean that the building is not near the edge of the town, but quite far inside the town limits. It would only make sense if the town itself is more than a few miles across, in which case we'd probably call it a city rather than a town.

One possible context where such an expression could be used would be

> I was amazed how big L.A. is. I had to go **a few miles into the city** to get to my hotel.

Comment: ThePhoton, I disagree about this use of "into." It's not uncommon at all. I hear it frequently. "I'm going into town." "Turn right a few miles into town." The unit of measure doesn't seem germane here. "A few blocks into town" would be fine in a small settlement, with "into" used in the same way. The interesting thing here, to me, is the omission of the article. Why, and when, do we say "into town" instead of "into **the** town" in such instances?

Comment: @P.E.Dant, I meant that logically (not grammatically) you can't go a few miles into a town that's only 3 blocks across.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337948/a-few-miles-into-the-town-verbless-clause-or-adverbial-phrase/337950?noredirect=1#comment777125_337950 See, it was the original question I posted on ELU, hoping to clear up some of my confusion. But anyway, I am afraid your use of "a few miles..." is not what I am trying to find. I am trying to establish the use of "a few miles..." as pure adverb phrase used with "there inversion". However, according to you, I think this use should be fine :  _There was a building a few miles into the city_. Does this sound idiomatic to you?

Comment: It is the same because there's no special meaning to "a few miles into the town" except an uncertain distance, perhaps between 3 and 5 miles, when travelling from the outer edge of the town at least roughly towards its center. It means the same thing in your examples as it does in mine.

Comment: @quetchalcoatle, there is a possible issue that communities large enough to travel a few miles from one edge towards the center and not come out the other side again are not usually called towns. They're more often called cities.

Comment: @quetchalcoatle _There was a building a few miles into the city_ is not idiomatic. It is a standard use of "into."

Comment: @P.E.Dant So do you mean it is correct to say _There was a building a few miles into the city _? You said it is not idiomatic ,which I take to mean wrong, and said it is a standard use, which I take to mean correct.

Comment: It is idiomatic in the sense that it is an easily understood English expression. It is not idiomatic in the sense that it doesn't have any special meaning other than the usual ones for the words that make up the expression.

Comment: So... _a few miles into the city, there was building_ is a common expression but does not contain any specific meaning other than what I am trying to convey? Does the commonness of it make it both idiomatic and unidiomatic?

Comment: @quetchalcoatle The usage is correct and standard, yes. Interestingly, although we might say _There was a building a few miles into **town**_, we would **not** say _There was a building a few miles into  **city**._ The article would be necessary when using "city," for reasons which aren't clear to me yet. One more reason to enjoy this site: even native speakers have much to learn!

Comment: @quetchalcoatle, what are you trying to convey?

Comment: @P.E.Dant THAT is interesting! Why is _a few miles into town, there was a building_ is valid while the other one with the city is not?

Comment: If you're trying to say that there's a building, and if you were outside the town, you'd have to travel a few miles in the direction of the middle of the town to get to it, then yes, your sentence conveys that. But if the building is outside the town, or only a few meters from the edge of the town, or the town is actually a city, then no, it doesn't convey that.

Comment: @quetchalcoatle, he means we don't drop the article for *city* the way we do for *town*.

Comment: Okay. I get it.Thank you! Just one more thing, if it is okay for you. Is there any difference between _There was a building a few miles into city_ and _a few miles into city, there was a building_?

Comment: The meaning is the same, but the first one emphasizes the fact that the building exists while the second emphasizes the location where it's found.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-idiomatic use of **into** as defined in Merriam-Webster's first entry:

> 1  —used as a function word to indicate entry, introduction, insertion, superposition, or inclusion

In your example, the definite article is not required, and it will usually be omitted:

> There was a building a few miles into <s>the</s> town.

Comment: We have no idea if the definite article is required or not in this sentence, since there is zero context.

Comment: @AlanCarmack. Actually, I think the only way it works is if the definite article is omitted.

Comment: There is an 'idiom; at play, but the idiom can be broken. We say *I'm going to lie down in bed* but we can say *I'm going to lie down in the bed.* We can also use 'the' in *There was a building a few miles into the town* when called for. *We had never been in Xzygstown before. It had some amentities. The town had two hospitals.There was also an airport a few miles into the the town, and we sent people to check it out.*

Comment: @AlanCarmack There is an idiom in play here: "into town," "going to town," "around town," all omit the definite article. As far as I can determine, "town" is the only word describing a settlement or polity which we treat in this way. We don't say "going into city," for instance, or "around county." BYU corpus has the form without "the" as far more common: "into _the_ town:" 222 "into town:" 1890. (Sorry, deleted original to edit it. Curse the 5 minute limit!)

Answer (score -2):

The question for me is the incompatibility of the idea of *location-at* and **into**.

We can *walk* a few yards *into* the jungle.

We can *drive* a few miles *into* the city.

You may have to *travel* a hundred miles  *into* the desert to find the oasis.

But can we say "The oasis is *located* a hundred miles *into* the desert"?

I have no problem with "The oasis is *encountered* a hundred miles *into* the desert".

Is "a hundred miles into" understood to be a place or a distance-traveled?

Comment: It was the original question :http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337948/a-few-miles-into-the-town-verbless-clause-or-adverbial-phrase/337950?noredirect=1#comment777125_337950

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "It".

Comment: Um..the original question...? It seemed that adverbial use of prepositional phrases whose head is "into" becomes licensed only when some words that denote distance are in front of "into." For example, you should say "a few miles into the city, there was a building", not "into the city, there was a building " By adverbial use of "into", I'm not including the ones that is used right beside the verb, like "go into" or "walked into".

Comment: Um, the original question was the original question?

Comment: Into the valley of death rode the six hundred.

Comment: For me the issue, as I said, is whether the prepositional phrase refers to motion/travel or to location.  I understand "A few miles into the city, there was a building" as "A few miles into the city, *we encountered* a building".  or "A few miles into the city, there is a building" as "A few miles into the city, *one will encounter* a building".

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much what is conveyed. God, I cannot see the deleted answer Peter posted. (Is it Peter?) Collin Fines commented under it, which  was very helpful.